# ListView Row Remove Button from SQL

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, sql-server-ce

I do have a ListView which i call from Database ( its selection of data ) in each row i have one Remove, Update Button. 
i Bind each button to the ID in listview so when i click it have to return that row value only!

BUT i want to call this value in my query Function to update or Remove the selected Row.
I'm not sure how to call this value into Query.

here is my binding sample:

```
<Button Name="delete" Click="Delete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=empID}">
```

Here is how i call it :

```
Button _button = (Button)sender;
string empID = _button.CommandParameter.ToString();
```

\sql stuff

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection();
                SqlCeDataAdapter ad = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(empID);

                String str = "UPDATE employee SET Isdeleted ='1' WHERE empID= " + empID;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", empID);

                ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Hope i can get some help as this Query will never worked so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will work but u should give it a try, I made it for a local sdf database

```
var con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + "|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf");
                String str = "UPDATE employee SET Isdeleted ='1' WHERE empID= '"+ empID +"'";
                var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(str,con);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception a)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection();
            SqlCeDataAdapter ad = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(empID);

            String str = "UPDATE employee SET Isdeleted ='1' WHERE empID= " + empID;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", empID);

            ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

this is a strange setup

perhaps:

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection();
            SqlCeDataAdapter ad = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            String str = "UPDATE employee SET Isdeleted ='1' WHERE empID= @empID";

            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(str);


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", empID);

            ad.UpdateCommand = cmd;
```

Comment: Its Work for delete function BUT still cannot figure out how to open new page by choosing one row from the list that will show the emp related data.                                                              I do bind the button to the empID in my list view and i expecting by clicking on detail button it show me the selected item data in new page.

Comment: i would suggest opening a new thread with the code that is giving you trouble.  it seems like you have much of the pieces you need already there, but your understanding of the commands is not quite where it needs to be.

Comment: In this case here you were creating a SQL query that consisted entirely of a number (empID), then creating a string that contained a non-parameterized SQL query and never used it, then adding a parameter to the SQLcommand.  your goal was to create a SQL command with a parameterized query and add the parameter and then execute the command.  you also had bound an update command to the SELECTcommand of the data adapter.  i modified that to bind to the update command.  you could also create a delete command separately and bind that to the deletecommand of the da.  hope this helps